# How to extend a Users model with another many to many relationship models Skills/Levels?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to extend a User model with associated Skills and Levels.  Where all users will have different skill levels for a variety of skills.  Im trying to figure out the most efficient way to setup the relationships to accomplish this.

Im currently setting Skill to Level as a many to many relationship. User to skills_has_levels is one to many but of no current use.

There are many skills a user can have and each skill can have a different level from no experience to expert.

```
[Tables]

users
    id, username, email, pwd, token, timestamps

skills (ie. laravel, angular, bootstrap, etc)
    id, name, order

levels (ie. none, beginner, intermediate, expert)
    id, name, value

skills_has_levels
    id, skills_id, levels_id, users_id
```

We have three models:

```
1) User (has many skills with levels)
2) Skill (has many levels)
3) Level (has many skills)
```

In the Skill model: (to have the users_id available: unused)

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Level’)
        ->withPivot(‘users_id’);
```

To list all users, their skills, and levels :

```
$users = User::all()->toArray();

foreach($users as $user)
{
    echo "User ID: ".$user->id;
    $skills = Skill::where(‘users_id’, ’=‘, $user->id)->get()->toArray();
    print_r($skills);
    echo "\n\n\n";
}
```

**Ultimately, I would want the User model to return a skills/levels array of all the associated user skills & their levels: skill name, skill order, level name and level value.**

What I currently do works but i feel it could be done better.

whats the best way to structure the relationships for the User model to connect to skills names and the associated levels values?

Is it possible to related the Skill/Level directly to the User model? So i only have to use the User model to access all of the associated skill and levels.

Or are my relationships wrong? Could change the models to this relationship:

```
A User has many Skill
    Skill has many skill types
    Skill has many skill levels
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database makes the work harder i guess
You can use dynamic properties if you want to make it available in usermodel

Models User <- -(Many to many) -> Levels <- -(Many to many)

```
protected $appends = ['skills_levels'];

public function getSkillsLevelsAttribute()
{

    $skills = // query to get all skills ->pluck('skill','id');

    $this->load('levels.skills')
    $levels = $this->levels->groupBy('skills.skill_id')->toarray();
    $output = [];

    foreach ($skills as $id => $skill) {
        $output[$skill] = [];
        if (isset($levels[$id])) {
            $output[$skill] = $levels[$id] // all levels user have for this skill
        }
    }
    return $output
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Normally I've seen other example where User to Skill is a many to many relationship and they put the skill level value (int) in the pivot table.  Im trying to standardize the skill levels. Im trying to also minimize the query calls to show all of the skills / levels for a given user. How would you structure the database instead?

Comment: how would you recommend to make it more efficient?

Comment: it should be , User -(hasMany)> Skills -(hasMany)> Levels (Both are many to many so you will have two pivot tables but it's easy to manage with laravel), then use `with('skills.levels')` in ur query  which won't result in many calls anyway after that, you can use dynamic properties as mentioned in my answer to map/format the data as you like or if you want it to happen automatically without the with just add `$this->load('skills.levels')` at start of `getSkillsLevelsAttribute()` method

Comment: the skills are set and so are the possible levels. how do i connect the skills to their levels? is skills.levels another pivot table similar to my skills_has_levels?

Comment: Skills-(hasMany)> Levels doesnt seem usable because every skill would have a relationship with each level without a purpose since both skills and levels are preset by me. Im unclear on how you recommend to connect the exact level of the user's skill.

Comment: I think this User -(hasMany)> Skills -(hasMany)> Levels works better for User, Role, & Permissions. As permissions are set to each roles.  However, for mine, every user has all Skills, which are set, but Levels, which are also set, are selected by the User.   So all Users will have the laravel skill but each unique user might have different laravel skill level.

Comment: user <- -(Many to many) -> Levels  <- -(Many to many) -> skills? since all users has all skills, you don't need direct relationship to skills, so basically in this case if a user has a level "senior", you can get the skill using the level model and then if you want to show the values, you just get all skills and check if the user has a level at that skill, i hope this makes sense but i don't know the exact usage but i understand what you mean. does this makes sense to you?

Comment: @Blitzo my updated answer should help you understand what i mean in the comments i hope

Comment: skills are php, perl, c++, python, swift, java, etc. levels are beginner, intermediate, & expert. what if a user has many skills at the level of expert? many skills can possibly be at the same level. other people do a simpler version where level is just a value in the User -> Skill pivot table.  im trying to standardize the levels so its normalized to the levels table.

Comment: @Blitzo if user has many levels of expert , either u only keep the biggest value and work like that, or not! and of course you can add, order column to specify which one is > than the other and about standardize , at that point i don't know.

Comment: thank you for your help. i will keep thinking about it, i just tried your suggestion and it doesnt work for what i want.  i might have to take 1 step down on db normalization and just enter the level value in the skills pivot table.

Comment: actually, i will just do what you recommended by the opposite. i will store the level_id in the Skills pivot and then just query the Levels to create a value key pair for all user skills and levels.  not as nice as i wanted but will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are few changes to be done on the table `skills_has_levels`

you should change

`skills_id` to `shareable_skills_id`

`levels_id` to `shareable_levels_id`

and finally update your classes like below

```
Class SkillsHasLevels
{
    public function shareable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

Class Skill
{
    public function shares()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(SkillsHasLevels::class, 'shareable');
    }
}

Class User
{
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Skill::class, 'shareable', 'shares');
    }
}
```

I hope this will return you the skills of the user

Comment: Thank you for your help.  However, your solution doesnt help me.  I already get something similar with just a many to many relationship between skills and levels. What I want is for Skill and Level to be accessible through the User model.

Comment: Skill has a many to many relationship to Level.  I want the User model to connect to this Skill/Level relationship. With your polymorphic relationship, I can only get what skills a user has but not the level of those skills.  It also shows the levels but not how the levels connect to which skills.

Comment: Ok, in addition add the below methods on your models `Skill` and `Level`

on `Skill` model
`public function levels()
{
    return $this->shares->levels;
}`

and on `Level` model
`public function skills()
{
    return $this->shares->skills;
}`

and i'm not sure this will work, you gotta try it

Comment: yes, this is what i tried.  it returns an array of the levels or an array of the skills but not of how they link. I would like it to return 'skill_1' => 'expert', 'skill_2' => 'beginner', etc